# Is it possible to emulate a felica card with an Android device?

Tags: nfc, smartcard, mifare, hce, contactless-smartcard

According to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html):

> Android (4.4 and above) supports emulating cards that are based on the NFC-Forum ISO-DEP specification (based on ISO/IEC 14443-4) and process Application Protocol Data Units (APDUs) as defined in the ISO/IEC 7816-4 specification

On the other hand, Falica cards are compliant with JIS: X6319-4 as per [Felica's wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FeliCa).

So, presumably it is not possible to use an Android device for emulation of Felica cards. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. But, there are currently patches from Sony on AOSP under review that would allow card emulation of Felica cards. See for example https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/128491/

Comment: Can android read and work with Felica card and Reader/Writer?

Answer (score 0):

Suica  card is emulated with Suica Mobile app, so it is possible